# Disable default Yasnippet snippets?

Tags: yasnippet

How do I disable all pre-existing yasnippet snippets?  I only want to use ones that I define myself.

Answer (score 6):

Customize the value of `yas-snippet-dirs` so that it doesn't include the default snippet directory. On recent yasnippet versions this will be the symbol `yas-installed-snippets-dir`.

---

```
yas-snippet-dirs is a variable defined in `yasnippet.el'.
Its value is ("~/.emacs.d/snippets" yas-installed-snippets-dir)

Documentation:
List of top-level snippet directories.

Each element, a string or a symbol whose value is a string,
designates a top-level directory where per-mode snippet
directories can be found.

Elements appearing earlier in the list override later elements'
snippets.

The first directory is taken as the default for storing snippet's
created with `yas-new-snippet'. 

You can customize this variable.
```